# How to attach a parity bit to a given 4 bit std_logic_vector?

Tags: vhdl

[Image of the DUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxnSl.png)

I'm trying to write an internal nibble transmission guarded by a parity bit. 
For this I want to write a transmitter/receiver logic which is shown in the image attached.

So I have a 4 bit input vector and generate a parity bit for it and here comes my problem.
I want to attach the parity bit to the input vector. But the input vector is only 4 bit. Is there a way to resize it by simply attaching the parity bit to the input vector or do i have to transmit the parity bit seperately?
And as a little side question in relation to the whole implementation: 
Do I have to create seperated processes for the receiver and transmitter like I have in my code or do I simply have to write one process containing both?

My first idea was to simply use an internal vector with 5 bit to attach the parity bit but the problem is that I only want the given input as output in the end and there is the same problem. In the process of the parity checker I have to fill the output vector which is 4 bit with the intern 5 bit vector and have no idea if this simply works like I tried in my code.

I hope you can understand the problem.
Thanks.

```
architecture rtl of odd parity is
    signal rxdat_s   : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal ok_s      : out std_logic;
    signal txdat_s   : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal secured_s : std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);

begin 
    odd_parity_gen: process ( txdat_s, clk ) is
        variable txdat_v      : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        variable secured_v    : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        variable odd_parity_v : integer;
    begin 
        txdat_v := txdat_s;

        odd_parity_v := xnor txdat_v;
        secured_v    := txdat_v + odd_parity_v;

        secured_s <= secured_v;

    end process odd_parity_gen;

    odd_parity_check: process () is
        variable ok_v         : integer;
        variable rxdat_v      : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        variable secured_v    : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    begin
        rxdat_v   := rxdat_s;
        secured_v := secured_s;
        ok_v      := ok_s;

        ok_v    := xnor secured_v;
        rxdat_v := secured_v;

        ok_s    <= ok_v;
        rxdat_s <= rxdat_v;


    reg: process ( clk ) is
    begin
        if rising_edge (clk) then 
            if nres = '0' then
                --reset all signals
            else
                --main logic
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this code has been cobbled together as example. You have input/output ports in an architecture and your ports are rather confusing: `rxdat_s` is an output and `txdat_s` is an input. Also you have no 5 bit output port which you need to send 4 bits plus parity.

Also this: `secured_v := txdat_v + odd_parity_v;` adds a an integer and a std_logic_vector which requires conversion or a library.

Assuming your parity generator is correct you can add a parity bit to the front using concatenation: the `&` operator.

```
 secured_s  <= odd_parity_v  & rxdat_s;
```

Or at the back using:

```
secured_s  <= rxdat_s & odd_parity_v;
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. That solved my problem.